# How to remove a record if it is duplicate and sum values :val

Tags: ruby, arrays

Given the following array of hashes:

```
list=[
  {:cod => "0001", :name => "name1", :val => 10},
  {:cod => "0001", :name => "name1", :val => 12},
  {:cod => "0002", :name => "name2", :val => 13},
  {:cod => "0002", :name => "name2", :val => 14},
  {:cod => "0002", :name => "name2", :val => 14},
  {:cod => "0004", :name => "name4", :val => 16},
  {:cod => "0004", :name => "name4", :val => 16},
  {:cod => "0004", :name => "name4", :val => 17},
  {:cod => "0005", :name => "name5", :val => 17},
  {:cod => "0005", :name => "name5", :val => 17},
  {:cod => "0005", :name => "name5", :val => 17},
  {:cod => "0006", :name => "name6", :val => 110},
  {:cod => "0006", :name => "name6", :val => 10},
]
```

How can I remove duplicate records?

Also, how can I find the sum of the values with the key `:val`?

Comment: Can you clarify the question? duplicate end sum values :val???

Comment: that's also an array, not a hash.

Comment: We're all answering different questions.  Do you want to remove records based on having a duplicate `:val` field, duplicate `:cod`-`:name` pair, or the whole hash being the same (or something else)?

Comment: Why havent you picked an answer already?

Answer (score 2):

You can pass a block to the method `uniq` of Array to determine the uniqueness.

```
list.uniq { |h| h[:val] }

=> [{:cod=>"0001", :name=>"name1", :val=>10},
 {:cod=>"0001", :name=>"name1", :val=>12},
 {:cod=>"0002", :name=>"name2", :val=>13},
 {:cod=>"0002", :name=>"name2", :val=>14},
 {:cod=>"0004", :name=>"name4", :val=>16},
 {:cod=>"0004", :name=>"name4", :val=>17},
 {:cod=>"0006", :name=>"name6", :val=>110}]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
list.map do |a|
  list.select { |b| b[:cod] == a[:cod] && b[:name] == a[:name] } \
       .reduce { |res, c| {:cod  => c[:cod], :name => c[:name], :val => ((res[:val] + c[:val]) || c[:val])} }
end.uniq { |h| h[:cod]}.each {|c| puts c.inspect}
```

output:

```
{:name=>"name1", :cod=>"0001", :val=>22}
{:name=>"name2", :cod=>"0002", :val=>41}
{:name=>"name4", :cod=>"0004", :val=>49}
{:name=>"name5", :cod=>"0005", :val=>51}
{:name=>"name6", :cod=>"0006", :val=>120}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use group_by:

```
list.group_by{|x| x[:cod]}.map{|k, v| v[0].merge({:val => v.map{|x| x[:val]}.reduce(:+)})}
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the answers so far, there's some confusion about what you actually mean by "remove duplicate records."  My interpretation of what you mean is that you wish to only remove records that are exact duplicates.  If so, then it is much simpler than the other solutions presented:

```
list.uniq
```

This returns:

```
[{:cod=>"0001", :name=>"name1", :val=>10},
 {:cod=>"0001", :name=>"name1", :val=>12},
 {:cod=>"0002", :name=>"name2", :val=>13},
 {:cod=>"0002", :name=>"name2", :val=>14},
 {:cod=>"0004", :name=>"name4", :val=>16},
 {:cod=>"0004", :name=>"name4", :val=>17},
 {:cod=>"0005", :name=>"name5", :val=>17},
 {:cod=>"0006", :name=>"name6", :val=>110},
 {:cod=>"0006", :name=>"name6", :val=>10}]
```

If you want the sum of the `:val` fields of the unique records, you can do this:

```
list.uniq.map{|h| h[:val]}.reduce(:+)
```

That grabs the unique elements (as above), then grabs the `:val` value from each, and finally applies `:+` (addition) to them to get the sum.

Comment: It would be nice if were that easy! That gives the sum of all :val's, not per unique id.

Comment: @pguardiario I'm not sure what you mean. It does exactly what I said it does: it discards duplicate "rows" (hashes where all three of `:cod`, `:name`, and `:val` are the same), then adds the `:val` fields that remain.

Answer (score 1):

```
list.uniq.group_by { |e| [e[:cod], e[:name]] }.map do |k, v|
  {k => v.map { |h| h[:val] }.reduce(:+)}
end

=> [{["0001", "name1"]=>22}, {["0002", "name2"]=>27}, {["0004", "name4"]=>33}, {["0005", "name5"]=>17}, {["0006", "name6"]=>120}]
```